# How to set up Kurento Media Server helpers?

Tags: cmake, kurento

I want to build Kurento Media Server against latest Fedora.

However, CMake fails to configure sources:

```
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "KurentoHelpers"
with any of the following names:

    KurentoHelpersConfig.cmake
    kurentohelpers-config.cmake
```

I installed `kms-cmake-utils`, as suggested, to `/usr/local/`. However, I still have this error, even if I set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to the folder where `kms-cmake-utils`'s `install` target put .cmake modules.

In fact, there is no `KurentoHelpersConfig.cmake` file in `kms-cmake-utils`.

How can I configure Kurento for Fedora?

Comment: Does googling for error message not help? E.g. this question in google list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kurento/JwwrJUHzjfU.

Comment: Of course I did. There was no solution, unfortunately, e.g. in your suggested link

Comment: Hm, [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/kurento/JwwrJUHzjfU/NSBE7mcXxcsJ) says that  `kms-cmake-utils hardcodes a cmake-2.8 path`, but `Debian jessie ships cmake 3.x and apparently that expects its modules in /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules.` It may be issue not only with Debian, but with cmake 3.x in general. Check that you have some Kurento-related scripts under `/usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules`

Answer (score 0):

Try installing to `/usr` instead of `/usr/local` because cmake is looking for modules in `/usr/share`

Executing cmake like this should fix the problem:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr
```

Comment: Already tried to install to `/usr`. Had very same problem, even if to specify `FindKurentoHelpers.cmake` file location in both `KurentoHelpers_DIR` and `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

You should append path of `KurentoHelpersConfig.cmake` to `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`, do that by adding this line to `CMakeLists.txt` :

```
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "/usr/local/share/cmake-3.5/Modules")
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems something wrong in cmake, it cannot read external CMAKE_MODULE_PATH, so I force set into its arguments line ( Ubuntu server x86_64 used), pay attention  **-DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH=$CMAKE_MODULE_PATH**.

```
HOME=`pwd`
BUILD=$HOME/build
export CMAKE_MODULE_PATH=$BUILD/usr/local/share/cmake-3.5/Modules

mkdir -p build
cd build

cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$HOMEDIR/build -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH=$CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ..
make DESTDIR=$HOMEDIR/build install
```